# BlackBerry - icon touch events

Tags: blackberry

My objectives:

- Design a screen which will have 4 icons.
- Get the click events for the icons for touchscreen devices.

Answer (score 1):

```
* Design a screen which will have 4 icons.
```

use a `BitmapButton` for each icons

```
* Get the click events for the icons for touchscreen devices.
```

Set `FieldChangeListener` for each button and perform your tasks there.

I think its enough

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. I would like to know whether it works or not. And field change listener works for both touch and non touch devices. So feel free to test it on any non touch device also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I have implemented the FieldChangeListener for the class  & for the specific Button I have called the following code.                          bitMapButton1.setChangeListener(this);                              Also , I am able to set the click events using the Anonymous inner class & get the click events using the protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) .

Comment: There are some touch events cases like protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {                                   int eventCode = message.getEvent(); switch (eventCode) {
    
case TouchEvent.CLICK:
case  TouchEvent.DOWN: }  The problem is that if we are not using the touchEvent API , we wont get the simple TAP events which I have tested & found the difference. With navigationClick ,  a simple tap on the screen is not providing any  response. Kindly help if you have already implemented the same.

Comment: `FieldChangeListener` has `fieldChanged` method to override. try to code on this. And if possible forget `navigationClick` for your case.   I'll need to see your code if its not working on `fieldChanged` method.